# iOS cronet ld error with enable_ios_bitcode flag

Tags: ios, bitcode, cronet

I build iOS Cronet with flag 'enable_ios_bitcode=true'. However, I meet the error below:

```
ld: section __bundle (address=0x003F8000, size=1136419986) would make the output executable exceed available address range for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../build/toolchain/mac/linker_driver.py", line 275, in <module>
    Main(sys.argv)
  File "../../build/toolchain/mac/linker_driver.py", line 85, in Main
    subprocess.check_call(compiler_driver_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['clang++', '-B', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/', '-shared', '-Xlinker', '-install_name', '-Xlinker', '@rpath/Cronet.framework/Cronet', '-Xlinker', '-objc_abi_version', '-Xlinker', '2', '-arch', 'armv7', '-Werror', '-Wl,-dead_strip', '-isysroot', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk', '-stdlib=libc++', '-miphoneos-version-min=8.0', '-fembed-bitcode', '-Wl,-ObjC', '-o', 'ios_clang_arm/obj/components/cronet/ios/arm/Cronet', '-Wl,-filelist,ios_clang_arm/obj/components/cronet/ios/arm/Cronet.rsp', '-framework', 'UIKit', '-framework', 'CoreFoundation', '-framework', 'CoreGraphics', '-framework', 'CoreText', '-framework', 'Foundation', '-framework', 'JavaScriptCore', '-framework', 'CFNetwork', '-framework', 'MobileCoreServices', '-framework', 'Security', '-framework', 'SystemConfiguration', '-lresolv']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I cannot figure out what the root cause is.
My xcode is 11.2 and build args.gn is that:

```
is_cronet_build=true 
is_component_build=false 
enable_ios_bitcode=true
target_cpu=\"arm64\" 
target_os=\"ios\" 
additional_target_cpus = [\"x64\",\"arm\"] 
enable_websockets=true
disable_file_support=true 
disable_ftp_support=true 
use_platform_icu_alternatives=false
disable_brotli_filter=false 
ignore_elf32_limitations=true 
is_debug=false enable_dsyms=true
enable_stripping=true 
use_xcode_clang=true 
ios_deployment_target=\"8.0\" 
enable_reporting=false
use_kerberos=false 
include_transport_security_state_preload_list=false
```

Does someone know how to resolve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Xcode 14 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-14-release-notes#Deprecations) bitcode is no longer required:

> Xcode no longer builds bitcode by default and generates a warning message if a project explicitly enables bitcode: “Building with bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target settings to disable bitcode.” The capability to build with bitcode will be removed in a future Xcode release.